# Is there a problem with R's download package?

Tags: r, linux, redhat, yum

Today I want to install R in linux/Red Hat.
When I type “yum info R”，the size of R is only 30K！
I failed to install R by "yum install R" and the version of R is not 4.0.2.

It's my problem or R's?

[image]

Comment: I think it have 30K-size because it is a [meta-package](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/1/html-single/packaging_guide/index#sect-Meta_Package). Did you tried to install it using `yum install R-*`?

Comment: The official documentation also relates that [you need to install it using EPEL release](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/redhat/#epel-for-centos-and-rhel). You could try this approach too.

Comment: Yes,I install it by using EPEL release. but the size of R in EPEL release is only 30k. And the version of R is 3.6.0 not 4.0.2.

Comment: The list of R packages available in [EPEL 8](http://mirror.cedia.org.ec/epel/8/Everything/x86_64/Packages/r/) and [EPEL7](http://mirror.cedia.org.ec/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/r/). So, there is no problem with your packages: the R version in the EPEL repository is the 3.6.

Comment: What version of R you get when using `dnf`?

Comment: 3.6 by using dnf. Now I run the R in linux，the log is “error while loading shared libraries: libRblas.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory” Do you know what's wrong with my R? Thanks.

Comment: I see you solve this problem in other publications. I think there is no problem with your R package, it was only an older version than 4, and R 4.0.2 is not available both at yum and dnf repos. If you want to use R >= 4, you will have to [install it from source](https://cloud.r-project.org/src/base/INSTALL).

Comment: Great~Thanks for your help~